# Se puede hacer en la v3 de google maps?

Tags: php, javascript

tengo este escript para google maps con el cual puedo hacer click y me muestra en un formulario su latitud y longitud, funciona bien y todo. mi pregunta es ¿ como lo puedo migrar a la version 3 de google maps? ya que el resto de mi sistema esta hecho en dicha version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadmap() {
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); 
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-36.5912852,-72.1210877), 15);    
      var point;
      point=map.getCenter();
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function (overlay,point){
         marker.setPoint(point);
         map.addOverlay(marker);
         marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<div style='font-size: 8pt; font-family: verdana'>Mi marca situada en<br>Latitud: " + point.lat() + "<br>Longitud: " + point.lng() + "</div>");
         GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function (overlay,point){
if (point){
      marker.setPoint(point);
      document.posicion.Latitud.value=point.lat()
      document.posicion.Longitud.value=point.lng()
   }
});
      });
   }



window.onload=loadmap
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal,

Basta con escuchar el evento click en el mapa y luego llamar a event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
   var myLatLng = event.latLng;
   var lat = myLatLng.lat();
   var lng = myLatLng.lng();
});
```

acá un fiddle de ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/jfergt/wxm25d9f/2/

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, quite la alerta y agregue lo siguiente 
document.posicion.Latitud.value=e.latLng.lat() y eso ya le pasa las coordenadas a mi formulario, ahora tengo que hacer un marker para ver dnd pongo cada click. me sirvio mucho tu respuesta :)

Comment: Con gusto, puedes marcar como útil la respuesta en la flecha hacia arriba.